# Mysql syntax using IN help!

Tags: php, mysql

i have a pictures table : `pictures(articleid,pictureurl)`

And an articles table : `articles(id,title,category)`

So, briefly, every article has a picture, and i link pictures with article using `articleid` column. now i want to select 5 pictures of articles in `politic` category.

i think that can be done using IN but i can't figure out how to do it.

Note: Please only one query, because i can do it by selecting articles firstly then getting the pictures.

Thanks

Comment: If each article has one image, why not put the pictureurl column in the articles table? Nothing is gained by normalising in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for an `IN` query instead of a `JOIN` this is an alternative to Alex's query:

```
SELECT pictureurl 
  FROM pictures 
  WHERE arcticleid IN (SELECT id FROM articles WHERE category='politic') 
  LIMIT 5
```

Comment: Of course, that is much less efficient than a JOIN so it should not be used in a simple case like this one.

Comment: Agreed, but that's what he asked for.

Comment: @St. John: I was just adding the standard disclaimer. I've seen way too much production code that was obviously written by someone who was never told why you shouldn't do things that way :)

Answer (score 2):

To get five pictures from articles in a category you could do this:

```
SELECT pictures.pictureurl
  FROM articles, pictures
 WHERE articles.id = pictures.articleid AND articles.category = 'politic'
 ORDER BY [your sort criteria]
 LIMIT 5;
```

You could consider rephrasing the question a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Rewritten for clarification (see comments):

If you like to keep your JOIN criteria separated from your SELECT criteria, you can write something like the below:

```
SELECT pictureurl
FROM pictures
JOIN articles ON id = articleid
WHERE category LIKE 'politics'
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 5
```

I find the intent slightly clear when it's written like that, and maybe it's just me, but I have encountered complex queries written in the `SELECT * FROM a, b, c` form that worked under MySQL 4 which choke MySQL 5, whereas the above format works fine with both.

Also, if you use uniform ID column names for conformity, and to avoid confusing yourself in more complex scenarios, you can use the `USING` clause instead. So if articles ID column is also named articlesid, the JOIN could be written like so:

```
SELECT pictureurl
FROM pictures
JOIN articles USING (articleid)
...
```

Comment: The 'USING' clause requires the same column name in both tables; unfortunately, in this example, they are different.  Consequently, you have to use an ON clause instead.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: That's why I started my answer by saying that using uniform column names would allow you to do it :)

Comment: OK: yes, the information is there, though it is not a direct answer to the question but rather an answer to a slightly different question.  I plead guilty to reading the SQL harder than the commentary.  You could have avoided the problem - to the extent it is a problem -  and got my up-vote (for using JOIN notation unlike everyone else) by giving the ON notation and then explaining the revised schema and the USING notation.  You can still get my up-vote if ...

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to use `IN` for this. `IN` serves when you nest queries or when you have a known set of values to check against.

To select 5 random images in the `politics` category:

```
SELECT pictureurl FROM articles, pictures WHERE pictures.articleid = articles.id AND articles.category = 'politics' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5
```